# Bought a phone on eBay, want to reinstall Android, but not sure which one to use

Tags: rom-flashing

I bought a phone on eBay named [XGODY 5.5" 3G 5MP 8GB](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Unlocked-XGODY-X15S-3G-Smartphone-5-5MP-Android5-1-Cell-Phone-Quad-Core-8GB-GPS/182107862300), and I want it to go back to the stock version, but how do I know what is the correct ROM to install on this phone?

Here is what the "About phone" says:

[image]

Comment: Is there any OEM related information in Device Bootloader?

Comment: Not sure, how would i check that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "generic" phone. ROMs need drivers that are specific for the specific processor, specific memory chip, specific camera module, specific cellular radio, specific Wi-Fi radio, specific Bluetooth radio, specific GPS chip, specific LCD screen, specific digitizer, etc.

From the eBay ad you linked to, the manufacturer of your phone is XGODY and the model is X15S. [Here is a link](http://www.xgody.com/5-xgody-x15s-3g-android-5-1-mobile-phone-smartphone-5mp-4-core-1-8gb-gsm-5mp.html) to the manufacturer's website.

Now, you need to find a ROM that was specifically made for the XGODY X15S. You can use your favorite search engines with such keywords as `xgody x15s stock rom`.